# What is the easiest way to write C extensions to Python for use in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, compilation, c

I would like to write some functions in C to call from the Python console in QGIS. What is the easiest way to do this? Does there exist anything comparable to Matlab's MEX?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to go to C vs staying in Python?

Comment: Speed, of course!

Comment: What are you doing that requires that kind of speed?  Have you done it in Python or using numpy already and speed tested it?

Comment: Well, it seems like being able to make C-based extensions to QGIS ought to be generally useful, as there are many tasks in GIS that are computationally intensive, and not all of them have been coded up for the general public yet. For example, if I want to resize a raster, but instead of using nearest-neighbor or quadratic/cubic interpolation, effectively taking the mean of pixels, I want to sum the pixels. This is necessary for resizing certain types of data (like population counts, for example), but there is no GDAL/SAGA/whatever function that can currently do it, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: ^This is a task that is computationally intensive, especially for large rasters and large target resolutions, especially because, as far as I can see, there is no good way to do it without loops. If I could code a C extension that would allow me to do this in QGIS it would make my life much easier. This is just one example.

Comment: ^I have written a program to do this in MATLAB, and I'm in the process of translating it to Numpy. It's slow in MATLAB and there is an upper bound on the resolutions it can work with feasibly. I'm assuming the same will hold for Python.

Comment: Have you considered Cython?

Comment: I've had a very quick look at the documentation for Cython, and I have the perception that it would be tricky to make it work within the PyQGIS environment. Is this impression correct or incorrect?